# Converting UTC date time to local date time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, dateformatter

I am trying to convert UTC date time to local date time and below is my code.

```
func dateTimeStatus(date: String) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!) // .string(from: dt!)
}
```

The above set of code works when the system(iPhone or iPad) language is set to **English(India)**. If I change the language to Japanese then a exception is thrown as below.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

at `return` statement.

I very well know that I am messing up with dateFormatter due to which **date is not recognised by the dateFormatter.date(from: date)**. Hence a nil value is assigned to the dt.

Any suggestions for generically using the date time format for all system language would be appreciable.

Comment: What is the exact value of the `date` string you are passing into this function?

Comment: `dt` is `nil`...coz date is not get converted. `dt!` force unwrapping of optionals causes run time error.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the kind reply, the date string which I pass to the function is **"6/5/18 12:47:54 PM"**

Comment: @MahendraGP yeah, you are correct about the date not getting converted thing. This exact same code works fine if the system language is set to **English(India)** but throwing error if I change the system language to **Japanese**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you attempt to parse a fixed format date string, you need to set the formatter's locale to a special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. This deals with many possible issues including the user's region and language, and the user's 12/24 hour settings.

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Then reset it to the user's locale along with the time zone.

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
```

You should also avoid forced unwrapping in case you get an unexpected date string.

Updated code:

```
func dateTimeStatus(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    if let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"

        return dateFormatter.string(from: dt)
    } else {
        return "Unknown date"
    }
}
```

You should also consider using a date and time style instead of a fixed format when presenting a date/time to a user. This ensures the date is in a friendly format. In your case you have a real issue.

Let's say you get a result of "06/05/18 10:30:00 am".

What date is that? Depending on where you live that could be June 5, 2018. It could be May 6, 2018. It could be May 18, 2006. It's very ambiguous.

Better to use something like:

```
func dateTimeStatus(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    if let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
        let userFormatter = DateFormatter()
        userFormatter.dateStyle = .medium // Set as desired
        userFormatter.timeStyle = .medium // Set as desired

        return userFormatter.string(from: dt)
    } else {
        return "Unknown date"
    }
}
```

Comment: The above fix works like charm and I used the date and time style as you suggested to avoid ambiguity. Once again thanks for the fix and suggestions.

Comment: Why in the second example there was a need to instantiate a second DateFormatter? This is an expensive class. Why not change its locale, timeZone, dateStyle, timeStyle and use it?